# Is it normal for my Windows virtual machine on Azure to be asking for activation of Windows OS?

Tags: azure

I built a virtual machine on Azure using the Windows Server 2016 VM option. For a while, it's been working fine, but recently, it's started asking me to activate Windows. I can't do any sort of customization of the interface until I do so.

Is this normal? Do I have to buy a Windows activation key for this VM and any future VM I build?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or for more help, please let me know

Comment: We had this issue when the VM does not have access to the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue, it's normal. The Windows Azure VM is activated by Azure, but it has a grace period if it is still not activated in the period, you will be asked to activate it.

> When the grace period has expired and Windows is still not activated,
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 and later versions of Windows will show
>   additional notifications about activating.

The more specific information, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-activation-problems#what-happens-if-windows-activation-period-expires).